# dart: How to add a new key value pair in object of list?

Tags: dart

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list1 = [
    {
      'value': 'Value number one',
    },
    {
      'value': 'Value number two',
    },
  ];
```

I want to add a new pair "item":0,
Then should be show like this

```
[
    {
      'value': 'Value number one',
      'item': 0,

    },
    {
      'value': 'Value number two',
      'item': 0,
    },
  ];
```

I dont know how to meke it this functionality.
Help me,Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the list and add the new entries.

For-loop approach:

```dart
for (final map in list1) {
  map['item'] = 0;
}
```

Functional approach:

```dart
list1.forEach((map) => map['item'] = 0);
```